# Cakephp i18n how to get content in default language if translation is not available

Tags: internationalization, cakephp-2.0

I am using i18n table and have 2 languages, english (default) and italian. When I am on italian version I get all the rows with italian translations and where there is no translation available I get nothing. How can I get english texts for the rows without italian translation?

[image: i18n Table]

When I have Config.language == ita and try to display $this->Career->find('all'); for this row I get empty title and body. Is there any easy way of get the contet in eglish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the model's locale to an array of the locales you want. By default it is set to the current `Config.language`.

```
$this->Career->locale = array('ita', 'eng');
$this->Career->find('all');
```

This will return all records. If the Italian translation is not present, it will give the English one.

Comment: Setting `Model->locale` to an array solves a bunch of problems! (For example, using an array allows records that don't have a particular translation available to "fall back" to the next one in the list.) [The book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html) should talk more about this. This answer was like the holy grail of solutions: I would upvote more than once if I could.

Comment: I was really happy for a minute when I found your answer, but this does not seem to work. If I set 'locale' to a single value 'eng' or 'pol' it works fine, but when I set $this->locale = ['eng', 'pol']; It seems to be ignored and no translation is taken into the result, just data from model table.